# updateAll query not working in cakephp

Tags: jquery, cakephp, sql-update, cakephp-2.0

I try to update the table posts using the updateAll command. But i got an error. I have wot tables namely users and posts. My controller is,

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Post extends AppModel {
public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className'    => 'User',
        'foreignKey'   => 'user_id',
        'fields'    => "User.id,User.name,User.uname"
    )
);
function updatePost($title,$content,$pid){
    $this->updateAll(
        array('Post.title' => $title,'Post.content'=>$content),
        array('Post.id' => $pid)
    );
}
}

?>
```

The error message is,
"Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Post 2, `Post`.`content` =

Models are the classes that sit as the business la' at line 1"

"SQL Query: UPDATE `blog`.`posts` AS `Post` LEFT JOIN `blog`.`users` AS `User` ON (`Post`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) SET `Post`.`title` = test_title, `Post`.`content` = sample body WHERE `Post`.`id` = 2 ";
How to correct it ?

Comment: 1. User has many Post that relationship is there in UserModel file ??? 2. Check that user_id exists in user table ?

Comment: yes id exist in user table not user_id, posts.user_id=users.id

Comment: thats good... change ur code like this and check                          
 $this->updateAll(
        array('Post.titile' => '\'' .$title. '\'',
     'Post.content'=>'\'' .$content. '\''),
        array('Post.id' => $pid)
    );

Comment: The problem is caused because you're using `updateAll()` which doesn't escape/quote values, see my answer for more info. You're probably looking for `Model::save()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you didn't include an actual **error message**? I can only see a query?

However, I *do* see a few issues;

- It looks like you've got a typo; `Post.titile` looks like a typo for `Post.title`
- Fields in CakePHP should be specified as an *array*, not a comma-separated string, so

  ```
      'fields'    => array("User.id", "User.name", "User.uname")
  ```

But again, please show the actual error message and/or what you're expecting and what you got instead

Additionally, as mentioned in the documentation, fields in `updateAll()` accept SQL expressions, so should be quoted manually. See [`Model::updateAll()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-array-conditions)

> Tip
>   The $fields array accepts SQL expressions. Literal values should be quoted manually using >Sanitize::escape().

Because you seem to be updating a *single* post, seems to me you're looking for `Model::save()` in stead?

See: [Saving your data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html)

### update

To do this with Model::save() rewrite your updatePost method to something like this;

```
function updatePost($title,$content,$pid){
    $this->save(
        array(
            'Post' => array(
                'id' => $pid,
                'title' => $title,
                'content'=> $content
            )
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Try...
$this->updateAll(
        array('Post.title' => "'$title'",'Post.content' => "'$content'"),
        array('Post.id' => $pid)
    );
```